# IIS7.5 URL Rewrite : do not translate POST to GET

Tags: post, iis-7, url-rewriting, iis-7.5, url-rewrite-module

I have a set of URIs with a common base-uri, where the first segment of the relative uri needs to be translated to various ports :

```
http://base-uri/service1/*  =>  http://base-uri:3000/service1/*
http://base-uri/service2/*  =>  http://base-uri:3001/service2/*
```

Both GETs and POSTs will be directed to these URIs.

Is it possible to configure an IIS 7.5 URL Rewrite rule so that a POST request continues to be a POST ? ( i.e. not translated to a GET )

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install the [Application Request Routing](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) module for that. You can not redirect the client as a redirect implies that the next request a client should do is a GET. So you have to proxy the request to the other server / port.